# Dynamically populate a dropdown CF7 field using data from google sheet or a third-party API

Tags: wordpress, google-sheets, contact-form-7

How can I retrieve data from a Google Sheets spreadsheet and populate a *Contact Form 7* drop down field with that data?

All solutions that I could find is how to send data from *Contact Form 7* to Google spreadsheet, and no solutions for reverse direction.

I have an API, from where I can get list of data, and I want to get that data by Zapier and populate Google sheet with that data, and then populate many *Contact Form 7* drop down fields, located in many websites, with data from spreadsheet.

Comment: why not go directly from the API to the CF7 dropdown?  Why the extra step via the googlesheet?

Comment: Ok, its is one of the solutions, how can I implement that feature?

Answer (score 0):

Following the comment discussion, one solution is to retrieve the dropdown list of options from the third-party source via the API and populate the CF7 form dropdown dynamically when the form is loaded.

This is possible using the Dynamic dropdown field available with the [Smart Grid layout](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) CF7 extension plugin.   The field can take 3 sources of dynamic data to populate a dropdown field: a list of taxonomies; a series of posts; or a filter hooked function that programmatically supplies a list.  This last option can be used to programmatically fetch the required list from a third-party source via the API.  Assuming the form dynamic dropdown field name is `zappier-select`, the plugin will automatically create a filter helper code that looks like this,

```php
add_filter( 'cf7sg_custom_dynamic_select','zapier_select_dynamic_options',10,3);
/**
* Filter dropdown options for dynamic drodpwn list of taxonomy terms.
* @param Array $options the option to filter.
* @param WPCF7_FormTag $tag field tag object.
* @param string $cf7_key  the form unique key.
* @return Array $options return either an array of <option value> => <option label> pairs or 2 arrays, one for values and another for attributes.
*/
function zapier_select_dynamic_options($options, $tag, $cf7_key){
  if('ui-form'!==$cf7_key || 'zapier-select' !== $tag->name){
    return $options;
  }
  //these are the label users will see when the dropdown opens.
  //you can group your options if need be. Let's assume you have an array of arrays of data to display in groups.

  $data = ... //fetch your data from your API third-party.

  foreach($data as $value=>$label){
    $options[$value]=$label;
    //if you are displaying more complex select2 fields, or imagegrid for dynamic checkbox, then add extra parameters into a 2nd array of attributes,
    $options['values'][$value]=$label;
    $options['attributes'][$value]= array('data-thumbnail'=>'<image url>');
  }
  return $options;
}
```

For more examples, see this youtube [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9he4Tca5o8&list=PLblJwjs_dFBsynXEstrV3fCIC7GBmK9HW&index=4&t=1198s).